# Android Studio cannot find devices

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, themes

I'm using Android Studio Giraffe. Currently I'm using new **UI-Theme (beta)** for my IDE. But I'm unable to find emulators or connected devices.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You you a talking about missing device selector, that is a currently known issue with new UI as of Canary 4. You can workaround this by adding the selector yourself:

1. Open `settings` -> `appearance & behavior` -> `menus and toolbars`
2. Select whichever toolbar you prefer (in my case its `Main Toolbar Center`
3. Click `Plus` icon, then `Add action`
4. Type `Select device` in search field, select it and save your changes.

[image]

If you are talking about `Running devices` and `Device manager` missing from sidebars, you can bring them back from main menu `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Device Manager` and `Running Devices`

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. But still select the device to run project on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you saw they in Device Manager?

Try

- wiping the emulator data
- deleting it and making a new one
- connect real device

Comment: Already connected real devices, it doesn't show.. neither say that it has been connected. When I click `run`, it build project in real devices

Comment: Can you run virtual device in "View > Tool Windows > Device Manager"?